# Beginner's guide to setting up SMPP with Java EE

Tags: smpp

I am a beginner in Java EE and SMPP, and I am looking for guidance on the steps involved in setting up SMPP with JEE. I would also appreciate recommendations for libraries that are well-suited for beginners.
I need to send and receive SMS messages.
I am looking for a solution that is easy to learn and use.

- What are the steps involved in configuring SMPP with Java EE and OpenSmpp?
- What are some best practices for developing SMPP applications with Java EE?
- What resources are available to learn about SMPP and Java EE?